Matthew 24:36 - "no one knows" - only present or includes the future?
GREEK GRAMMAR
Matthew 24

36“But concerning that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels
of heaven, nor the Son, but the Father only.

Does that mean no one knows:

At the time the statement was made
Including the future


Why is this downvoted?

Maybe some Trinitarian trembles to the idea that Jesus also in future, would have some information not available to him, like it happened when he was among men... I've upvoted you.

@SaroFedele I think that has good starting point based upon the verse He emptied Himself

Philippians say Jesus was obedient until He died on the cross. One might infer that He learned "all things" upon His Ascension, but it's a dangerous supposition, lacking a more direct statement. On the other hand, and equally weak, is an inference from use of the present tense that it is a continuing state.

@MasonBarge All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to Me . . . except for knowing certain things? Seems more logical that this means all His self-limitations were removed.

If Jesus knew then Jesus contradicts his own statement. Applying sophistry to say or imply that he knew is delusive. He didn't not say "this I'm telling you as the God, and this I am telling you as a man". Claiming that because "he emptied himself" as the reason why he did not know is unconvincing. He is not God if he did not know. How could Jesus be God if he is empty of the attributes of God?.

@ Maximus1987 - You left out the "third" alternative! Greek verb tenses often contain two time frames! (See Ray Grant answer.) So a verb may mean "now , continuing on into the future." (i.e. Present tense)

This is a delicate matter and we should not be dogmatic.  However, what we can say is this:

the verb tense of "know" in Matt 24:36 is οἶδεν (oiden) which is perfect indicative active.  Thus, technically, it should be translated as "no one has known" or similar as does the LSV & YLT.

However, as stated above, one should not be too dogmatic about this as the NT are not always overly precise about their verb tenses.  If Matthew had intended to mean that no one knows at any time, past present of future, one may have expected the aorist infinitive tense suggesting all time, but he avoided this.  This may indicate that no one knew at the time Matthew wrote but that it may become evident, even if to only a select few at some future time.

Mark 13:32 uses exactly the same verb tense as Matthew.
Matt 24:42 uses the same perfect indicative active tense
Matt 24:44 uses the same tense but with a different verb, δοκεῖτε (dokeite) = "expect/think"

If we take the verb tense here as it is, it leaves open the possibility that perhaps Jesus (after, in resurrection glory) may know, but this is unstated.

Yes, thank you for clarifying this. My overall impression is that Christ will know all things. Philippians 2:8 says He was obedient "even to death on the cross", but I can't tell whether this refers to "how" obedient He was, or "when" He was obedient.

@MasonBarge - Christ's existence was divided into three stages - His eternal pre-existence; His incarnation on earth during which He was obedient even to death; and His eternal resurrection life as King and High Priest.

"No one knows" means no one knows. That includes all creation until He returns. But the God has always known.
God the Father knows God knows the end from the beginning. (Isaiah 46:10) And He knows everything that happens in between and beyond.
Jesus Jesus is fully God and fully man, "but emptied himself, by taking the form of a servant, being born in the likeness of men." (Philippians 2:7) Jesus intentionally limited his abilities and knowledge while He walked the earth, as it is written in Philippians 2:6: "though he was in the form of God, did not count equality with God a thing to be grasped." In this way, Jesus lived a life by the Holy Spirit that is also available to us. I say this to explain why Jesus did not know at the time, though He is God the Son. Today, there is no reason to think He does not know.
Us But we don't know and we will not know when the end shall come. This is why we're told "Therefore, stay awake, for you do not know on what day your Lord is coming. But know this, that if the master of the house had known in what part of the night the thief was coming, he would have stayed awake and would not have let his house be broken into. Therefore you also must be ready, for the Son of Man is coming at an hour you do not expect." (Matthew 24:42-44)

Greek GrammarThe answer is simple syntax. The first part of this verse referred to a future event: that day and hour. Of course, Jesus referred to the awesome Second Coming. "That" is quite a definitive adjective. No questioning here about "that" Greek word pointing to something in the future.
The word "day" is often used in the O.T. to refer to the LORD's appearance. (Amos 8:3, 9, 13, 9:11, Micah 4:6, 5:10, 7:ll)
No one KnowsThe second part of this verse uses the "present tense" (in English) and is translated no one knows. In the Greek grammar, the tense is the "perfect tense" and  contains the thought of something happening in the past and with continuous action on through the present.
(*)---------------------------/--------------------------------------> "no one knows"Past.........................Present..............................................Future.......>In translating from the Greek to the English the present tense is the closest verb tense that conveys the meaning of the Greek verb. Emphasis on "continuous" action.

Matthew 24:36 (and Mark 13:32) oudeis oiden "no one knows" (third person singular) Thus NKJV, NLT, NASB, HCSB, Berry Greek Interlinear.
Matthew 24:42, 25:13 (and Mark 13:33,13:35) ouk oidate "you do not know" (second person plural) Thus NKJV, NASB, NLT, HCSB, Berry Greek Interlinear.

EmphasisJesus presented a "list" of those who do not know, for emphasis: neither you, angels, or Son, but just the Father. He was quite emphatic about there being no signs of the Second Coming!
This exclusive Providence of God was echoed in Jesus's words later, after His resurrection:

It is not for you to know the times or dates the Father has set by His own authority. But you shall receive power... (Acts 1:7-8)

But ConcerningJesus had just given many discernable signs of the End of the Old Testament Era culminating in the Destruction of Judea and the Temple itself! (Matthew 24:1-35) However when He introduced the topic of the End of the New Covenant Era (that is, the Second Coming), Jesus used the words, peri-de ("but concerning...") This was a conjunction of contrast.
That "Day" (Second Coming) was not to have any harbingers, no signs or warnings, as was the opposite case with the End of the Jewish Era, which had many signs.
So Jesus is affirming that there will be a Second Coming at a future day and hour. But from the first century (when Jesus spoke) until the Second Coming actually happens in the future, there will be no signs. There are no alleged "End Times Signs" so often touted in prophecy conferences. That is, "no one will ever know" until it occurs.
Christians, however, are not left in the dark. They have the Light of the World guiding them...until that Day!
This is the simple Greek linguistic understanding. (Koine Greek)

We need to know the Hebraic idioms of the Jewish feast days as most of the fulfillment of the Mosaic law centered around the feast days.  Yeshua knew when "the end" of that temple would happen as He told His disciples the things to watch for and then said,

Lo, I did tell you beforehand. (Matt. 24:25, YLT)   and


Verily I say to you, this generation may not pass away till all these may come to pass. (Matt. 24:34, YLT)

Yeshua knew the events that would take place before the temple was destroyed.  He knew and connected the abomination of desolation foretold in Dan. 12:11 which He cites in Matt. 24:15 and directly links the time of that abomination to the destruction of Jerusalem and their temple to that generation of the 1st century AD, that very generation in which He was speaking to them.  That abomination is rephrased in Luke 21:20-22 as the armies surrounding Jerusalem.

20 `And when ye may see Jerusalem surrounded by encampments, then know that come nigh did her desolation; 21 then those in Judea, let them flee to the mountains; and those in her midst, let them depart out; and those in the countries, let them not come in to her; 22 because these are days of vengeance, to fulfil all things that have been written. (YLT)

Then, why do we dismiss His knowing the time of their desolation at the hands of the Roman legions?

And concerning that day and the hour no one hath known -- not even the messengers of the heavens -- except my Father only;  (Matt. 24:36, YLT)

Past tense.  Trying to understand these English words without knowing how they were used and understood by the disciples in relation to their feast days hides the original meaning.  His disciples knew exactly what Yeshua was referring to by that phrase as it was well known to them.  It was a saying that identified a particular feast day, namely the Feast of Trumpets on the 1st of Tishri.
No one knew when that day would be before the Sanhedrin affirmed and stated the 1st day of the month of Tishri.  They could not exactly know because they had to wait for the two witnesses to report the sighting of the new moon.  Since the feast of Trumpets was always held on the 1st of Tishri, then no one knew the day or the hour until it was officially declared.  And, since the timing of the appearance of the new moon each month is under YHVH's control, then only the Father in heaven "hath known" that hour.
The phrase "no one knows the day of the hour" was an idiom for the Feast of Trumpets, and Yeshua was giving His disciples a clue.  He did not tell them the year, but He did tell them the time of the year - the 1st of Tishri.
The Feast of Trumpets was a day of judgment, and was also associated with the time the Father sent His Son to collect His bride. See Hebroots, and BereanBibleChurch.
Excerpt from my blog post The Signs of the Feasts - Part II
"In the chapter discussing the destruction of the temple, Christ deliberately used the Hebraic idiom for the Day of Trumpets.  He told his disciples the day the temple would be completely destroyed – Yom Teruah!
Yom Teruah was a memorial, a day of remembrance.  There was another day in which another besieged city fell at the blast of trumpets. Josh. 6:1-5,

Now Jericho was straitly shut up because of the children of Israel: none went out, and none came in. 2 And the Lord said unto Joshua, See, I have given into thine hand Jericho, and the king thereof, and the mighty men of valour.


3 And ye shall compass the city, all ye men of war, and go round about the city once. Thus shalt thou do six days. 4 And seven priests shall bear before the ark seven trumpets of rams’ horns: and the seventh day ye shall compass the city seven times, and the priests shall blow with the trumpets.


5 And it shall come to pass, that when they make a long blast with the ram’s horn, and when ye hear the sound of the trumpet, all the people shall shout with a great shout; and the wall of the city shall fall down flat, and the people shall ascend up every man straight before him.”  (KJV)

That long blast of the ram’s horn, the shophar was the last trumpet, the last trump.
The 4th “shophar” trumpet blown on the Day of Trumpets is known in Hebrew as the “Tekiah Gedolah” or  “the last trump”.

“In a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trump: for the trumpet shall sound, and the dead shall be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed. (1 Cor. 15:52, KJV)


And I saw the seven angels which stood before God; and to them were given seven trumpets.”  (Rev. 8:2, KJV)

In Matthew ch. 24 Christ was telling His disciples when that temple would be destroyed, and He linked its destruction to several events that would happen: first the tribulation (Matt. 24:21-28); then the judgment of the wicked (Matt. 24:29-30); and the gathering of the elect (Matt. 24:31); all with the warning to watch for the thief in the night (Matt. 24:42-44).
Christ went on to explain in Matt. 25:1-13 of the five foolish virgins who did not prepare before the wedding day.  They did not watch and plan ahead.  This is related to the need for the Hebrews to plan ahead for Yom Teruah as they did not know the day or the hour of the memorial, which was also the time Christ would come to collect His bride.
Yeshua knew the day and the hour, and He also knew the year because He told them to watch for the armies that would surround Jerusalem.  The present prefect indicative was for that generation to know the future event that would happen before that generation passed.  It was future to them, still to come in their day and time.
But, it happened at the destruction of that temple in AD 70 and so is not still future to us.  To view it as a still future event for those of us who are reading of this prophecy almost 2,000 years after that generation is anachronistic.  And, to think that a future destruction of a temple that no longer exists is still ahead of us is not logical.
The time was their present day, and their future day of their generation. It does not belong to any other generation but that generation of the 1st century AD.  It was the double fulfillment of the 1st destruction of Jerusalem and the Solomon temple of the prophecies from Ezek. 22, Dan. 9-12, Amos 9, Joel 2, etc.

Answer
The expression “no one knows” in Matthew 24:36 denotes only present and it doesn’t include the future.
Explanation
There was a time when Jesus as the Word existed “in the form of God” but He did not consider the to-be-equal-with-God something to be held on but emptied Himself of His Godhead and became a human being “in the form of a servant”. This is described in Philippians 2:6-8.
“the form of a servant” = 100% human being.
This means, though the Person was God, He left (“emptied”) all the power and glory, that is, the whole attributes of Godhead behind.
So, while He was a full human being, He experienced genuinely all the human limitations. He hungered, felt thirsty, tired, sleepy etc. He also didn’t know the exact day and hour of His coming.
“the form of God” = 100% God, that is, the Almighty God.
This means the same Person has no limitations of a physical human being but has the full attributes of the Almighty God.
Logically, limitation of knowledge is a human trait not applicable to God who is omniscient, omnipresent, omnipotent etc.
If Jesus was in the form of God, He went back to the form of God after the Resurrection (John 13:3).
So, He doesn’t lack any knowledge as God now.
While living on earth as a human being, He also said:

“For the Father loves the Son and shows to Him all things
which He does. And He WILL SHOW Him greater works than these in
order that you may marvel” (John 5:20).

This means Jesus knew that He “will know” (in future) the day and hour after His Resurrection!
What is more, today, He is:

“who being the shining splendor of His glory, and the express
image of His ESSENCE (not simply an outward form but the very
sum-total of God), and upholding all things (ta panta) by the
word of His power” (Heb 1:3).

Which creature can sustain “all things” (ta panta) by its power? Only the Creator God can do that. And Jesus does it now!
Logically the One who upholds “all things” (the entire Universe) by His own Power, doesn’t now know about “that day and hour”; this is absurd.
The Greek Grammar
Matthew 24:36
The particular word used in this verse is “οἶδεν” which is a verb in the ‘Perfect Indicative Active’.

“The perfect indicative active in Greek is used to describe a
completed action that has results that are still relevant in the
present.
[Meaning]:-
The perfect tense in Greek describes a completed
action that has results that are still relevant in the present.
[Translation]:- The perfect indicative active can be translated into
English using the present perfect tense, such as "they have done".”

(from the internet)
So the correct translation would be “no one has known” the day or hour.
So this has nothing to do with future tense. That means, things can change in the future.
John 5:20

“And He (Father) WILL SHOW (δείξει) Him greater works than these”.

The “deixei” for “will show” is in ‘Future Indicative Active’.

“The future indicative active in Ancient Greek is used to describe
actions that will occur in the future by the subject of the
sentence. These actions are definite and must occur”.

(from the internet)
So when Jesus said that not even the Son has known about the day and hour, He meant the time of His Incarnation.
This will have changed definitely in the future as God the Father will show Him greater things as He stated in John 5:20 after the Resurrection when He is going to sustain the entire Universe with His power!
Conclusion
Jesus, as a human being, didn’t know the exact day and hour of His second coming.
Today as God He sustains the entire all things with His power. Today as genuine true God, He is omniscient and knows the day and hour.

Theologically, I 100% agree but I was looking more for a grammar answer (that's why I added the grammar tag).Why could grammar disagree with the theology? The Bible uses tension: passages that are in conflict with one meaning and therefore encode information in the correct reconciliation.

If the grammar includes the future, then that would point to a possible exception or different roles between the Father and resurrected Son.

Okay, I will update my answer later. Thanks for the clarification.
